# Treeview to excel with with Expand And Collapse buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to export Treeview to excel with expand And collapse capabilities. 
Maybe there is open source project that do this task or I need to develop one with the excel API?

Answer (score 1):

you can use epplus and use the excel grouping feature, an example for using that is shown here:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/263201

another possibility is using the excel object model, with that you can insert the tree row by row, and then add the grouping via for example

```
Rows("1:70").Group
```

Comment: Thanks, Are you sure there is no better solution?